# Losing variables values between form and javascript

Tags: javascript, mysql, forms

I am having a lot of trouble with form values, first I echoed out the MYSQL insert function to see what data was attempting to be put into the database and for one MYSQL insert function it was replacing most of my entered data into `''` so first I thought it was my `preg_replace` function in the PHP part of my code but I removed this and the same thing was still happening, I am now not sure where it has gone wrong but I am guessing somewhere between the Javascript and the form. I really am lost on where to turn now. The INSERT function for the User table works perfectly fine it picks up all the entered data but with this Member table it is a different story

Javascript

```
     function restrict(elem){
    var tf = _(elem);
    var rx = new RegExp;
    if(elem === "email"){
        rx = /[' "]/gi;
    } else if(elem === "username"){
        rx = /[^a-z0-9]/gi;
    } else if(elem === "mobileNumber"){
            rx = /[^0-9]/gi;
        }
    tf.value = tf.value.replace(rx, "");
}
function emptyElement(x){
    _(x).innerHTML = "";
}
function checkusername(){
    var u = _("username").value;
    if(u !== ""){
        _("unamestatus").innerHTML = 'checking ...';
        var ajax = ajaxObj("POST", "signup.php");
        ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if(ajaxReturn(ajax) === true) {
                _("unamestatus").innerHTML = ajax.responseText;
            }
        };
        ajax.send("usernamecheck="+u);
    }
}
function signup(){
    var u = _("username").value;
    var e = _("email").value;
        var m = _("mobileNumber").value;
    var p1 = _("pass1").value;
    var p2 = _("pass2").value;
    var ci = _("city").value;
        var pc = _("postcode").value;
        var c = _("country").value;
        var d = _("dateOfBirth").value;
    var g = _("gender").value;
        var ln = _("lastName").value;
        var fn = _("firstName").value;

    var status = _("status");
    if(u === "" || e === "" || p1 === "" || p2 === "" || c === ""
        || g === "" || m === "" || ci === "" || pc === "" || d === ""  ){
        status.innerHTML = "Fill out required fields";
    } else if(p1 !== p2){
        status.innerHTML = "Your password fields do not match";
        }else if(m.value !== 11 && isNaN(m)){ 
        status.innerHTML = "Please enter valid mobile number";
         }else if(d === "dd/mm/yyyy"){ 
        status.innerHTML = "Please enter your date of birth";



    } else {
             //ajax to send form data to php
        //hides sign button
                _("signupbtn").style.display = "none";
        status.innerHTML = 'please wait ...';
                //wait until php verifies data
        var ajax = ajaxObj("POST", "signup.php");
        ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if(ajaxReturn(ajax) === true) {
           //if sign not succesful unhide button
                    if(ajax.responseText !== "signup_success"){
                    status.innerHTML = ajax.responseText;
                    _("signupbtn").style.display = "block";
                } else {
                    window.scrollTo(0,0);
                    _("signupform").innerHTML = "OK "+u+"";
                }
            }
        };
        ajax.send("u="+u+"&e="+e+"&p="+p1+"&c="+c+"&g="+g+"&ci"+ci+"&m"+m+"&pc"+pc+"&d"+d);
    }
}
```

Form

```
<form name="signupform" id="signupform" onsubmit="return false;">
    <div>Username: </div>
    <input id="username" type="text" onblur="checkusername()" onkeyup="restrict('username')" maxlength="16">
    <span id="unamestatus"></span>
    <div>Email Address:</div>
    <input id="email" type="email" onfocus="emptyElement('status')" onkeyup="restrict('email')" maxlength="88">
    <div>Create Password:</div>
    <input id="pass1" type="password" onfocus="emptyElement('status')" maxlength="16">
    <div>Confirm Password:</div>
    <input id="pass2" type="password" onfocus="emptyElement('status')" maxlength="16">
     <div>First name:</div> 
     <input id="firstName" type="text"  /><br />
     <div>Last name:</div> 
     <input id="lastName" type="text"   /><br />
     <div>Mobile number*:</div>
     <input id="mobileNumber" onfocus="emptyElement('status')" onkeyup="restrict('mobileNumber')" maxlength="16">
    <div>Gender:</div>
    <select id="gender" onfocus="emptyElement('status')">
      <option value=""></option>
      <option value="Male">Male</option>
      <option value="Female">Female</option>
    </select>
    <div>Country:</div>
    <select id="country" onfocus="emptyElement('status')">
      <?php include_once("country_list.php"); ?>
    </select>
    <div>City:</div>
    <input id="city" onfocus="emptyElement('status')">
    <div>Postcode:</div>
    <input id="postcode" onfocus="emptyElement('status')">
    <div>Relationship Status*:</div>
    <select id="relationshipStatus" >
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value="Single">Single</option>
        <option value="Taken">Taken</option>            
                </select>
    <div>Date of Birth*:</div>
    <input id="dateOfBirth" type="text" onfocus="emptyElement('status')">
    <button id="signupbtn" onclick="signup()">Create Account</button>
    <span id="status"></span>
  </form>
```

INSERT functions

```
 $sql = "INSERT INTO Member (`firstName`, `lastName`, `gender`, `emailAddress`, 
                        `city`, `country`, `postCode`, `relationshipStatus`, `mobileNumber`, `dateOfBirth`)       
                    VALUES('$fn', '$ln', '$g', '$e', '$ci', '$c', '$pc', '$rs', '$m', '$d')";
            $query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql);
            $uid = mysqli_insert_id($db_conx);

            // Establish their row in the useroptions table
           $sql = "INSERT INTO User (`Userid`, `username`, `password`, `accountType`) VALUES ('$uid','$u','$p','$accountType')";
           $query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql);
```

Comment: Please don’t build the query string to send via AJAX yourself (especially if you don’t know what you are doing), but use the mechanism your lib (I assume you are using one, where f.e. your ajaxObj comes from?) offer for this instead – in jQuery f.e. `serialize`.

Comment: the ajaxObj comes from the ajax module that I have put in a separate file to reuse every time I need ajax, Thanks for the tip. I have solved my problem now do I delete the question?